# Can I fast-path reasoning like this (simplifying trig expression)?

Tags: trigonometry

Find [image] if [image]

tg = tan (tangent function)

Textbook solution is as lengthy as this:

[image]

But can I fast-path reasoning like

$tan(\alpha) = 1 => sin(\alpha) = cos(\alpha)$ (both *sin* and *cos* being either negative, or positive)

Now I just substitute $cos(\alpha) \ne0$ (because tan with such cos is defined) and just get $${7*cos(\alpha)-6*cos(\alpha)\over3*cos(\alpha)-5*cos(\alpha)} = \frac {cos(\alpha)}{-2*cos(\alpha)} = \frac {-1}{2}$$

Is my reasoning strict enough?

Comment: Yes this approach is fine.

Comment: You could also leave some "slow" steps out in the given solution, then you get $$=\frac{7-6\tan α}{3\tan α-5}=-\frac12.$$

Comment: What does the textbook solution change at the third "="?

Comment: @Peter Foreman I'd accept it as an answer!